# How to save a list of numpy arrays of different sizes to disk?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, save, load

I have numpy arrays of different lengths, for example

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
b = [5,6]
c = [7,7,7]
d = [12,24,43,54,66,77,88]
```

They are packed together in a list (or a dictionary)

```
the_list = [a,b,c,d]
```

Each array is about 500 elements long, and the list is about 1000-10000 arrays long.

I want to save this list **to a single file** on disk with the following requirements in order of importance:

1. Runtime On Read
2. Human readable file format
3. Runtime on Write

Using pandas like so:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(the_list)
df.to_csv(path, header=None, index=False)
```

Only writes the first element of every array.
I'm guessing there is a better (working) way, either with pandas, pickle, or something else

Comment: Do you really need `numpy` arrays here? Can't you just convert to list and use JSON?

Comment: You could make a dictionary of arrays whose key is the variable name and picked I

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I need the arrays to go into the writer and out of the reader as numpy arrays. if it makes sense to turn them into other stuff, that's fine.

Comment: @Gulzar Minimal code shouldn't be a priority as long as it's readable, maintainable and generally follows [The Zen of Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/).  Also you shouldn't specify *preferences* but instead identify a set of *requirements* and have them fulfilled, no matter what.

Comment: have you looked at [`np.savez`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.5/reference/generated/numpy.savez.html#numpy.savez)?

Comment: @a_guest your'e right. edited.

Answer (score 2):

I'd probably go with [`numpy.savez`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.5/reference/generated/numpy.savez.html#numpy.savez).  This *isn't* a human readible format so maybe it won't work for you, but it is really easy to use (you read the file using `numpy.load`).

If having it legible for humans is really important, I'd go with json -- It's a language agnostic interchange format that is well known and widely used (probably due to it's popularity in web development).  You can write your own encoder/decoder using the builtin facilities in the `json` module (it's really quite easy), or you can let something like [`json-tricks`](https://json-tricks.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) do that work for you.

Answer (score 0):

This works in my pc:

```
the_list = [a,b,c,d]
df_list = pd.DataFrame({ i:pd.Series(value) for i, value in enumerate(the_list) })
df_list.to_csv('./df_list.csv')
```

[the csv file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G22dm.png)